# SQL ORDER BY before TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI, or in Python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, geopandas

I am performing a query on PostrgreSQL using Python (pyscopg2)

The data is point geometries, stored in patched of 600 points per patch.

I am trying to streamline and speed up the process, previously I would do the following:

1. explode the geometry
2. order by x, y, z
3. save the result to a new table
4. Use TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI(1) to sample the data to 1%
5. save back to the database

To speed things up I'm trying to reduce the amount of writing to the database and keep the data in python as much as possible.

The old code:

Exploding the patches

```
    query = sql.SQL("""INSERT INTO {}.{} (x,y,z)
                SELECT
                    st_x(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as x,
                    st_y(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as y,
                    st_z(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as z
                from "public".{} order by x,y,z;""").format(
        *map(sql.Identifier, (schema_name, table_name2, table_name1)))
```

sampling the data:

```
    query2 = ("CREATE TABLE {}.{} AS (SELECT * FROM {}.{} TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI ({}))".format(
        schema, table_name_base, schema, imported_table_name_base, sample_base))
```

This works, but I would like to either:

A) Perform this as a single query, so explode --> order by --> sample.

B) Perform the explode in SQL, then sample in python.

For A) I have attempted to nest/subquery but PostgreSQL will not allow TABLESAMPLE to work on anything that isn't a table or a view.

For B) I use `data = gpd.read_postgis(query, con=conn)` to get the data directly into a geopandas dataframe, so sorting is then easy, but how do I perform the equivalent of `TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI` to a geopandas dataframe?

Option A is my preferred option, but it might be useful to test option B incase I end up allowing different sampling methods.

Edit:

This is the visual result of:

```
    query = """
    SELECT
        PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry as geom,
        st_x(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as x,
        st_y(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as y,
        st_z(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as z
    FROM {}.{}
    TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI ({})
    ORDER BY x,y,z, geom 
    ;
    """.format(schema, pointcloud, sample)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am a little lost.  A random sample is a random sample and doesn't depend on the ordering.  If you want a sample that depends on the ordering, then use an nth sample.  That would be:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by x, y, z) as seqnum
      from (select st_x(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as x,
                   st_y(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as y,
                   st_z(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as z
           from "public".{}
          ) t 
     ) t
where seqnum % 100 = 1;
```

Or perhaps you just want to take the sample *and then order afterwards*, which you can also do with a subquery.

Comment: Since the points are ordered by patch they are already ordered in groups of 600 points. For some reason applying Bernoulli() seems to be selecting random patches, ordering the points first gives the  random behaviour on the actual points. I do not understand why it does this, but it does.

Comment: @SpatialDigger . . . *Bernoulli* sampling is random.  It doesn't make a difference if the input source is ordered or not.   Bernoulli is sampling the *rows* from the table, so you are getting complete rows (which seems useful to me).  But you seem to want a random sample of points, which is what this does (as well as the previous suggestion of just `random() < 0.01`.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the visual output of a point cloud following the Bernoulli sample.

Comment: @SpatialDigger . . . I understand that.  Bernoulli sample is going to take all points for 1% of the rows in the table.  Using `random() < 0.01` (with a subquery) or the solution here is going to take a random sample of all points.  Use whichever is what you really want to do.

Comment: I think it will be best to select all the points from the database table, bring that into geopandas, then sample from there, it will be more tie costly, but it has the benefit of allowing different sampling strategies.

Comment: @SpatialDigger . . . I don't agree.  You can sample in the database, which should be a big performance win.  Move 1% of the data to the app should be a significant speed increase.  But if you do that, it might be faster to explode on the application side, depending on what the data structures look like.